# XML element with attribute and content using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I generate the following XML using JAXB?

```
<sport type="" gender="">
    sport description
</sport>
```

Answer (score 145):

Annotate type and gender properties with `@XmlAttribute` and the description property with `@XmlValue`:

```
package org.example.sport;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Sport {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String type;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String gender;

    @XmlValue;
    protected String description;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Answer (score 11):

Here is working solution:

Output:

```
public class XmlTest {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlTest.class);

    @Test
    public void createDefaultBook() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(new Book(), writer);

        log.debug("Book xml:\n {}", writer.toString());
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "book")
    public static class Book {

        @XmlElementRef(name = "price")
        private Price price = new Price();


    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "price")
    public static class Price {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "drawable")
        private Boolean drawable = true; //you may want to set default value here

        @XmlValue
        private int priceValue = 1234;

        public Boolean getDrawable() {
            return drawable;
        }

        public void setDrawable(Boolean drawable) {
            this.drawable = drawable;
        }

        public int getPriceValue() {
            return priceValue;
        }

        public void setPriceValue(int priceValue) {
            this.priceValue = priceValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

22:00:18.471 [main] DEBUG com.grebski.stack.XmlTest - Book xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book>
    <price drawable="true">1234</price>
</book>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to a similar answer to help those looking at this as a solution. Good answer, btw. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15429363/1686575

Comment: you save me ! :D 
I resolved with the utilization of  @XmlValue

Answer (score 10):

The correct scheme should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Sport"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Sport" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
jaxb:version="2.0">

<complexType name="sportType">
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="string">
            <attribute name="type" type="string" />
            <attribute name="gender" type="string" />
        </extension>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>

<element name="sports">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="sport" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                type="tns:sportType" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Code generated for SportType will be:

```
package org.example.sport;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sportType")
public class SportType {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String type;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String gender;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
    return type;
    }


    public void setType(String value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String value) {
        this.gender = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated Solution - using the schema solution that we were debating. This gets you to your answer:

Sample Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Sport"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Sport" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
jaxb:version="2.0">

<complexType name="sportType">
    <attribute name="type" type="string" />
    <attribute name="gender" type="string" />
</complexType>

<element name="sports">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="sport" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                type="tns:sportType" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Code Generated

SportType:

```
package org.example.sport; 

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sportType")
public class SportType {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String type;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String gender;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }


    public void setType(String value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String value) {
        this.gender = value;
    }

}
```

Sports:

```
package org.example.sport;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "sport"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "sports")
public class Sports {

    protected List<SportType> sport;

    public List<SportType> getSport() {
        if (sport == null) {
            sport = new ArrayList<SportType>();
        }
        return this.sport;
    }

}
```

Output class files are produced by running xjc against the schema on the command line

Comment: Not using XSD. Using JAXB annotations.

Comment: Sure, but you can produce a very simple XSD to describe the above XML structure to generate Java code files for you with the annotations on. Alternatively you can build them up manually, the annotation structure should be in the docs. The advantage of using an XSD is it's very quick to change the structure and regenerate the java code files. It depends how comfortable you are with either approach http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my issue is how to generate given XML using annotations manually. How I need to define my entity class fileds ?

Comment: See my new solution above, really hope this helps