# Unable to unmarshal array of elements with inner text

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

We have stuck in sth that should be trivial. We have the following XML:

```
<someRoot>
  <aList>
    <item atr="value">otherValue</item>
    <item atr="someValue">someOtherValue</item>
    ....
  </aList>
</someRoot>
```

We are unable to get the "otherValue" or "someOtherValue" which is inner text in the item node. No problem with the attribute. I'm not going to post all annotation test we have done to make this simple.

Any way, how should the SomeRoot, AList and Item classes be annotated to make this work?
Sample should work with and array and retrieve both attributes and inner text.
Thanks in advance to the community.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML element with attribute and content using JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@XmlValue` for the property mapping to the inner text.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String atr;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: Yeap... that's it..After a few hours of stupidity obfuscation... :-) Thanks Blaise!