# JAX-B customized XML output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm working with the ECCP protocol in order to integrate my CRM with the Elastix Call Center Module. The protocol uses a XML structure defined as follows:

```
<request id="1">
   <request_type> <!-- this will be mapped to the Java request class -->
       <attributes>
       </attributes>
   </request_type>
</request>
```

and

```
<response id="1">
    <response_type> <!-- this will be mapped to the Java response class -->
        <attributes>
        </attributes>
    </response_type>
</response>
```

I'm using JAX-B to map XML to Java classes but the problem is that I have to put the JAX-B generated XML inside a `<request></request>` XML every request and extract the content from `<response></response>` in every response because the ECCP protocol defines that every request and response needs to nested to their respective elements.

Here's the code I'm using to do that:

```
document = createDocument();
Element requestWrapper = document.createElement("request");
requestWrapper.setAttribute("id", String.valueOf(wrapped.getId()));
document.appendChild(requestWrapper);

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(wrapped.getClass());
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(wrapped, requestWrapper);
```

Exemplifying:

One of ECCP's protocol operation is JAX-B-mapped into a class like this (getters and setters were omitted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "loginagent")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EccpLoginAgentRequest implements IEccpRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "agent_number")
    private String agentNumber;

    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

And JAX-B outputs the following:

```
<loginagent>
   <agent_number>username</agent_number>
   <password>password</password>
</loginagent>
```

But what the ECCP's protocol requires is:

```
<request id="1"> <!-- id is an auto-increment number to identify the request -->
    <loginagent>
       <username>username</username>
       <password>password</password>
    </loginagent>
</request>
```

The question is: is there any other way to achieve in any other better way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this in this post: [XML element with attribute and content using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb)

So I've mapped a EccpRequestWrapper object as the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
public class EccpRequestWrapper {
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    @XmlAnyElement
    private IEccpRequest request;
}
```

and then my request JAX-B outputs my request the way ECCP protocol requires.
The `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlAnyElement` annotation did the trick.

```
<request id="1">
   <login>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>****</password>
   </login>
</request>
```

A good JAXB guide can be found here https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

You can probably check out the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation which will help you wrap the same content both for request and response. For the inner part you can create the separate class and map all the fields appropriately. I hope this helps you a little bit.

EDIT:
Sorry for the long response time. You need to create a wrapper class with the inner structure defined as an @XmlElement. Here's the way to achieve that XML structure:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
public class RequestWrapper {

@XmlElement(name = "loginagent", required = true)
protected EccpLoginAgentRequest loginagent;

public EccpLoginAgentRequest getLoginagent() {
    return loginagent;
}

public void setLoginagent(EccpLoginAgentRequest loginagent) {
    this.loginagent = loginagent;
}
}
```

And here's the EccpLoginAgentRequest structure:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EccpLoginAgentRequest {

@XmlElement(name = "agent_number")
private String agentNumber;

@XmlElement(name = "password")
private String password;

// getters and setters omitted
}
```

So in result, you can print the XML you want like that:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Wrapper.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,    true);

EccpLoginAgentRequest request = new EccpLoginAgentRequest();
request.setAgentNumber("1");
request.setPassword("pass");

Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.setLoginagent(request);

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(wrapper, System.out);
```

It will give you the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request>
    <loginagent>
        <agent_number>1</agent_number>
        <password>pass</password>
    </loginagent>
</request>
```

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the @XmlSeeAlso annotation docs, but I'll improve my question to explain better the problem.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could check the question again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks again, @reallol, but it will work only when I send a EccpLoginAgentRequest object, while what I really need is to be able to send objects from any class that extends EccpRequest.