# Parsing wrapped attributes with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given something like:

```
<root>
    <wrapper>
        <wrapped id="..."/>
        <wrapped id="..."/>
    </wrapper>
</root>
```

how can I map it to this POJO:

```
public class Root {
    public Set<UUID> myIds = new LinkedHashSet();
}
```

I am wondering since `@XmlElement( name = "wrapped" ) @XmlElementWrapper( name = "wrapper" )` works somewhat similar to what I want, is there something to get the attribute?

note: i am not using moxy so as far as I know, I cannot use xpaths. I am trying to avoid the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb?rq=1

Comment: That is a different schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your root class a little bit,
so that it will contain a `Set<Wrapped>` instead of a `Set<UUID>`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "wrapper")
    @XmlElement(name = "wrapped")
    public Set<Wrapped> myWrappeds = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

And you need a separate class for the `<wrapped>` elements.
Surprisingly for me, you don't need an `@XmlJavaAdapter` for `id` here, because JAXB already has a [built-in converter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/model/impl/RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java#846) between `java.util.UUID` and `String`.

```
public class Wrapped {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public UUID id;
}
```

I have checked the above with this XML input file

```
<root>
    <wrapper>
        <wrapped id="550e8400-e29b-11d4-a716-446655440000"/>
        <wrapped id="550e8400-e29b-11d4-a716-446655440001"/>
    </wrapper>
</root>
```

and this `main` method which reproduces the original XML:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    File file = new File("root.xml");
    Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your time and looking into this. Getting `Set<UUID>` instead of `Set<Wrapped>` is what I am looking for so there is no need to code for converting between `UUID` and `Wrapped` objects. For now I am using what basically what you have + `@XmlJavaAdapter` to do the conversion between `UUID` and `Wrapped` objects so the pojo still has `Set<UUID>`