# Add XML inner tags

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to add inner XML tags like this:

```
<payment_responses page="1" per_page="100" total_count="23" pages_count="1">
    <payment_response>      
        .......
    </payment_response>
</payment_responses>
```

I tried this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_responses")
public class PaymentResponses {

    @XmlElement(name = "payment_response")
    private List<PaymentResponse> paymentResponse = new ArrayList<PaymentResponse>();

    @XmlElement(name = "technical_message")
    private String technical_message;

    public PaymentResponses() {
    }
    .........
}
```

How I can add these tags: `page="1" per_page="100" total_count="23" pages_count="1"`?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the concept of xmlElement with xmlAttribute.

In your example page, per_page... are attributes and the element is payment_response

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

Comment: Can you show me please working example how to implement this?

Comment: You can check the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb

Comment: I understand that you only have problems with the attributes (page, per_page,...) and that element (payment_response) is working correctly?

Comment: I found how to implement it. Thanks.