# JAX-B deserialize custom tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given an object as such :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "node")
public class Node {
    @XmlElement(name = "data")
    private String data;
}
```

I want to get it serialized this way :

```
<node><data [string]/></node>
```

How can I do this ?

My string contains multiple attributes like `x='1' y='2'`.

Comment: You are talking about `XML` attributes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb You are not allowed to put a `String` just like that inside node. You need to parse `data` and create `POJO` with annotated properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to model your Java field `data` not as `String`,
but as a class of its own (let's call it `Data`).

So, instead of

```
@XmlElement(name = "data")
private String data;
```

you need

```
@XmlElement(name = "data")
private Data data;
```

The new `Data` class then holds Java fields `x` and `y`

```
public class Data {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "x")
    private int x;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "y")
    private int y;
}
```

Note that `x` and `y` need to be annotated by [`@XmlAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) instead of `@XmlElement`.

This will produce XML like for example

```
<node><data x="1" y="2"/></node>
```

Comment: I used XmlAnyAttribute with a map and it worked well !